# Append user name to field at time of modification

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I recently discovered the simple, yet powerful macro that allows me to record the date and time a field was last modified, which is extremely important in the clinical research I am conducting. I would love to use the same macro builder to do a similar action with users, recording the username of the person who last modified a field.

Is this as simple as a macro and I'm just missing the equivalent of a "Date()" expression for the current user (e.g., "User()"), or are we talking VBA?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`CurrenUser()` function returns database user name.

`Environ("USERNAME")` function returns windows user name, but this function takes it from environment so could be fooled by enemy.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I clearly need to improve my searching skills; I feel like I should have come across this on Google or SO.